# Keyboard disappears on focus in Mobile Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

In mobile browser, when I click input the keyboard shows up and then in one second it disappears. On desktop browser it's OK.

I try:

```
$('.login-input').focus(function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
})
$('.login-input').focus(function (e) {
  $(this).unbind('blur');
})
```

but it doesn't work.

It works like blur was set in focus: (But it's not like that)

```
$('.login-input').focus(function (e) { $(this).blur })
```

When I double click on '.login-input', the keyboard doesn't disappear.

Comment: Why do you have all these `br` tags in your code? I think that doesn't work. Please add an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can reproduce this.

Comment: sorry, i correct this, in code i don't have `br`

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am running into this now.